# set Child`s Id to parent of parent`s unique id in Vanilla Javascript in Firebase blog

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a blog. In my `loadBlog` function I am creating a div, which gets a unique id for every single loaded blog post: `div.id = newPost.postID;`
In this div's div I have a button embedded, what I would like to achieve is when I enter editing mode (where I can edit and delete posts) **the button to get the parent of parent`s id** with an attached string + "delete".

E.g

> div id=postId-0

set the delete button's

> button id=postId-0-delete

```
function enterEditingMode() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('admin-help-editing-hidden')[0].classList.toggle('admin-help-editing');
    let button = document.getElementById('editing-mode-button');
    if (button.innerHTML === "Editing mode") {
        button.innerHTML = "Exit editing mode";
        const parentObject = document.getElementsByClassName('post-title');
        [...parentObject].forEach((parent, i) => {
            let addDeleteButton = document.createElement('button');
            addDeleteButton.innerHTML = "Delete";
            addDeleteButton.setAttribute("onclick", "deletePost()");
            addDeleteButton.id = //how to set dinamic id
            addDeleteButton.className = "delete-button";
            parent.appendChild(addDeleteButton);
        })
    }
else if (button.innerHTML === "Exit editing mode") {
        ...
        }
    }
}

function loadMyBlog() {
    let posts = firebase.database().ref('posts/');
    posts.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    let newPost = snapshot.val();
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'blog-post';
    div.id = newPost.postID;
....}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out myself. The reason why I could't get it because when I was trying to add addDeleteButton.id. it didn't actually exist in the DOM yet. That is why I could't get parent's ID. I had to appendChild(addEditButton) first and then 
`addDeleteButton.id = addDeleteButton.parentNode.parentNode.id + "-delete";`